# What is the difference between "a" and "the" in these sentences

Tags: articles

There are these 2 examples for "ability" on oxford learner's dictionary.(https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/ability_1?q=ability)

> This program has the ability to adapt to its user.

> She has an uncanny ability to predict what consumers will want.

Would you tell me why the word "ability" from the first sentence is with "the", and why the second one is with "an"?

Comment: In the first example it is a design feature of the program. In the second it is more vague, and there is no *specific* ability; it is more of an instinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your examples are not consistent - you have added an adjective (uncanny) to the second one. This will lead to difficulties in the explanation, so I will take the examples as

**This program has *the* ability to adapt to its user.**

**The** is, in basic terms, a demonstrative adjective that is related to the demonstrative adjective **that**.

Whereas **that** is used when pointing at something, **the** is used with a noun that is

(1) already known by the listener ("The moon is bright" = we all know what "the moon is),

or

(2) is about to be described by the speaker ("The tree in my garden is tall." - I have described the tree - it is the tree **in my garden** and not any other tree.

**The** is used to indicate that the noun it qualifies is a specific noun.

*(We could say "**This program has *that particular* ability [that allows it] to adapt to its user.** but **the** does that job for us.)

2. **This program has *an* ability to adapt to its user.**

A/an is, in basic terms, an adjective of quantity. It is related to "one".

"**A/an noun**" means "**one example of a noun**" or "one example from among many examples of a noun" - **a/an** is non-specific.

(We could say " **This program has *one ability amongst many of its abilities* to adapt to its user.**)